# Grep from multiple files and get the first n lines of each output

Tags: unix, grep

Let's say I have `f` files.

From each file I want to `grep` a pattern.

I just want `n` pattern matches from each file.

What I have:

`strings <files_*> | grep <pattern> | head -<n>`

I do need to use `strings` because I'm dealing with binaries, and from this command I am only getting `n` lines from the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep has a -mX option that allows you to specify how many matches.  However, adding this to your piped command line, is going to stop at the the first X matches total... not per file.

To get per-file count, I came up with this:

```
for FILE in `ls -f <files_*>` ; do strings "$FILE" | grep -m<X> <pattern> ; done
```

Example (searching for "aa" the files that match x* and returning up to 3 lines from each would be:

```
for FILE in `ls -f x*` ; do strings "$FILE" | grep -m3 aa ; done
```